# Game crashes continuously and auto save is corrupted

Tags: crash, games

I was playing the video game Star Wars: Empire at war on my newly acquired Mac. I'm not having any trouble starting up the game or anything—it's just the game crashes every time after a while I start playing the game. And after it crashed I tried clicking on the autosave and the when I do that, the game crashes again. So what do I? I've had to restart three times now, all approximately 3 hours I invested in. This is the report I've been getting.

```
Process:               Empire at War [16051]
Path:                  /Users/USER/Downloads/*/Empire at War.app/Contents/MacOS/Empire at War
Identifier:            com.aspyr.empireatwar
Version:               1.05 [CL 26868] (1.05 [CL 26868])
Code Type:             X86 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Empire at War [16051]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-12-29 22:59:39.319 +0900
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.2 (15C50)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        34EB1855-F779-AF28-81C0-A4AABF90E7D5

Sleep/Wake UUID:       34125913-A038-4068-BC9C-AB07DA4F322E

Time Awake Since Boot: 100000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       13000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: disabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000000001000-0000000000ae4000 [ 10.9M] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Users/USER/Downloads/*/Empire at War.app/Contents/MacOS/Empire at War

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   ???                             0000000000 0 + 0
1   com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x005e1f10 SmartPtr<TextureClass>::operator=(TextureClass*) + 32
2   com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x00481732 BaseComponentClass::Delete_Mega_Texture() + 26
3   com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x0046e261 CommandBarClass::Reset_Data() + 451
4   com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x00476cc2 CommandBarClass::~CommandBarClass() + 50
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x95eb2979 __cxa_finalize_ranges + 318
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x95eb2a01 __cxa_finalize + 59
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x95eb2cf6 exit + 62
8   com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x0056bbcb luaD_throw + 65
9   com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x00568f5e luaG_errormsg + 257
10  com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x00569026 luaG_runerror + 192
11  com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x00565760 LoadInt + 54
12  com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x00566273 luaU_undump_state + 559
13  com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x0056a107 lua_undump_state + 61
14  com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x004f48a8 LuaScriptClass::Load_State(ChunkReaderClass*) + 710
15  com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x001d7a91 PlanBehaviorClass::Load(ChunkReaderClass*) + 775
16  com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x001dd49b PlanManagerClass::Load(ChunkReaderClass*) + 239
17  com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x001ca616 AIPlanningSystemClass::Load_Chunk(ChunkReaderClass*) + 100
18  com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x001f4046 ServicedAISystemClass::Load(ChunkReaderClass*, bool) + 34
19  com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x001f4c78 TacticalAIManagerClass::Load(ChunkReaderClass*, bool) + 182
20  com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x0010c10c AIPlayerClass::Load(ChunkReaderClass*, bool) + 104
21  com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x002c5b95 PlayerClass::Load(ChunkReaderClass*, bool) + 157
22  com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x002c9b9b PlayerListClass::Load(ChunkReaderClass*, bool) + 201
23  com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x000fa3a8 SaveLoadManagerClass::Load(int) + 598
24  com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x0008de5d LoadGameDialogClass::Load_And_Start_Selected_Saved_Game() + 267
25  com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x0008df24 LoadGameDialogClass::GUI_Message_Callback_Function(GUICallbackMsg const&) + 58
26  com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x00375fcf GUIDialogClass::System_Update(unsigned long, Vector2 const&) + 739
27  com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x0037b439 GUIDialogManagerClass::System_Update(unsigned long) + 215
28  com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x001024c5 WinMain + 7145
29  com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x00039d19 sEventLoopEventHandler(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*) + 65
30  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x950492ff _InvokeEventHandlerUPP(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*, long (*)(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*)) + 36
31  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x94ff17b0 DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 1832
32  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x94ff09c4 SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 402
33  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x94ff082a SendEventToEventTargetWithOptions + 40
34  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x95029e26 ToolboxEventDispatcherHandler(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*) + 1994
35  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x94ff1bff DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 2935
36  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x94ff09c4 SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 402
37  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x95003b6d SendEventToEventTarget + 34
38  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x951a0c8e ToolboxEventDispatcher + 82
39  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x951a0b4f RunApplicationEventLoop + 240
40  com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x00039dce InstallEventsAndRunGameLoop() + 166
41  com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x0003a131 main + 253
42  com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x0000299a _start + 216
43  com.aspyr.empireatwar           0x000028c1 start + 41

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9751f812 kevent_qos + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x9020270e _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 234
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x902022e2 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9751ed76 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x96ade52d _pthread_wqthread + 1289
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x96adbf72 start_wqthread + 34

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9751ed76 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x96ade52d _pthread_wqthread + 1289
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x96adbf72 start_wqthread + 34

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9751ed76 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x96ade52d _pthread_wqthread + 1289
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x96adbf72 start_wqthread + 34

Thread 5:: com.apple.audio.IOThread.client
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9751784a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x97516c34 mach_msg + 68
2   com.apple.audio.CoreAudio       0x90178b44 HALB_MachPort::SendMessageWithReply(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned long, unsigned long, mach_msg_header_t*, bool, unsigned int) + 140
3   com.apple.audio.CoreAudio       0x90171d52 HALB_MachPort::SendSimpleMessageWithSimpleReply(unsigned int, unsigned int, int, int&, bool, unsigned int) + 72
4   com.apple.audio.CoreAudio       0x901701c0 HALC_ProxyIOContext::IOWorkLoop() + 1392
5   com.apple.audio.CoreAudio       0x9016fb34 HALC_ProxyIOContext::IOThreadEntry(void*) + 156
6   com.apple.audio.CoreAudio       0x9017bc8c ___ZN19HALC_ProxyIOContextC2Emj_block_invoke + 20
7   com.apple.audio.CoreAudio       0x9016fa59 HALB_IOThread::Entry(void*) + 71
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x96adea26 _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x96ade99c _pthread_start + 155
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x96adbf96 thread_start + 34

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9751ed76 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x96ade52d _pthread_wqthread + 1289
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x96adbf72 start_wqthread + 34

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x11767836  ebx: 0x00c512b8  ecx: 0x00c4f9e0  edx: 0x17678280
  edi: 0x00c4fe68  esi: 0x00000000  ebp: 0xbfffc068  esp: 0xbfffc04c
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00010202  eip: 0x00000000   cs: 0x0000001b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0x00000000

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000014
Trap Number:     14
```

Comment: Theres more to the crash report but due to the limitation on the word count I was only able to post a fraction of it

Comment: If you start a different game, does it crash?

Answer (score 2):

The bad autosave is a known issue if you have the disk game, and there is no fix.  See [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/star-wars-empire-at-war.1626472/). I have the periodic crashes as well, and don't know of any fix except to download the new version from the istore.